# SQL Server : pick value from earlier row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns `OrderNo`, `CategoryType` and `CategoryName`. `CategoryType` tells us if the category in `CategoryName` is the main category or a sub-category. It is set to `blank` for main categories and is set to `Sub Category` for sub-categories.

I need to create a 4th column `Main_Category_Name` which is populated for each row with the name of the main category which is "right above" the sub-category. "Right above" is decided based on `OrderNo`.

The code I have currently written uses the `LAG` function and populates the category name from the previous row - which is not quite what I want.

I've included my code, and the current vs desired output below. Can someone please help. Thanks.

[image]

```
drop table if exists temp

create table temp
( 
    OrderNo int, 
    CategoryType varchar(100), 
    CategoryName varchar(100)
)

insert into temp values (1, '', 'Cat1')
insert into temp values (2, '', 'Cat2')
insert into temp values (3, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat1')
insert into temp values (4, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat2')
insert into temp values (5, '', 'Cat3')
insert into temp values (6, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat1')
insert into temp values (7, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat2')
insert into temp values (8, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat3')
insert into temp values (9, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat4')
insert into temp values (10, '', 'Cat4')


select 
    *, 
    case 
        when CategoryType = 'Sub Category' 
            then lag(CategoryName, 1, 0) over (order by OrderNo) 
            else '' 
    end as Main_Category_Name
from temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a typical `outer apply top 1` pattern.

Side note: `insert ... values` can do multiple rows at once! Separate each row with a comma. Example included:

```sql
create table #temp
(
   OrderNo int, 
   CategoryType varchar(100), 
   CategoryName varchar(100)
);

insert #temp values 
(1, '', 'Cat1'),
(2, '', 'Cat2'),
(3, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat1'),
(4, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat2'),
(5, '', 'Cat3'),
(6, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat1'),
(7, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat2'),
(8, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat3'),
(9, 'Sub Category', 'SubCat4'),
(10, '', 'Cat4');


select      t.orderNo,
            t.categoryType,
            t.categoryName,
            Main_Category_Name = p.CategoryName
from        #temp    t
outer apply (
               select   top 1 CategoryName
               from     #temp
               where    OrderNo < t.OrderNo
                        and CategoryType = ''
                        and t.CategoryType = 'Sub Category'
               order by OrderNo desc
            ) p;
```

Comment: Also, thank you for the `insert ... values` suggestion - very helpful!